# Compress files (client side) and upload

Tags: javascript, html, upload, zip

What HTML5/Javascript method I can use to upload and compress files on the client side?

The code to select multiple files:

> Note: If you upload files occupying this method, the server is slow to
>   compress files, to prevent overloading is preferable to compress from
>   the client side

```
 <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <input type="file" name="fileselect[]" multiple="multiple">
    <input type="submit">
 </form>
```

The code as I'd like it to be:

```
<script>
 ...
</script> 
...
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <input style="display:none" type="file" name="singlezipfile">
    <input type="submit">
 </form>
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no built-in functionality to achieve this...

But you can do this using FileReader API and javascript zip implementation like this one http://stuk.github.io/jszip/